# Reactive Extensions buffer events until requested

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

There is a demo app I prepared.

```
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Reactive.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var stored = new ConcurrentQueue<long>();

        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20))
            .Subscribe(it => stored.Enqueue(it));

        var random = new Random();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay((int)(random.NextDouble() * 1000));
                var currBatch = stored.ToArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < currBatch.Length; i++)
                {
                    long res;
                    stored.TryDequeue(out res);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(",", currBatch) + "]");
            }
        });

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

It simulates independent consumer, which fires at random time intervals. In real app event source would come from file system, though might be bursty.

What this thing does is storing indefinite ammount of events in concurrent queue, until consumer decides to consume gathered events.

I have a strong feeling that this code is unsafe. Is it possible to reproduce such behaviour in purely Rx manner?

If not, can you suggest better / safer approach?

Comment: Ok, after messing up with Andrew's solution, it appeared that I actually wanted is to pull observable. This is easily done with the Collect extension method.  

var ys = xs.Collect(() => new List<long>(), (list, x) => { list.Add(x); return list; }, lst => new List<long>());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var producer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20));
var random = new Random();

Task.Run(async () =>
{
    var notify = new Subject<int>();
    producer.Window(() => notify)
        .SelectMany(ev => ev.ToList())
        .Subscribe(currBatch => Console.WriteLine("[" + string.Join(",", currBatch) + "]"));

    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay((int)(random.NextDouble() * 1000));
        notify.OnNext(1);
    }
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: <3 Thanks for such quick response.